# Export secret name in cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-secrets-manager

I am creating a secret using a Cloudformation template, the problem that I have is that the only value that can be exported is the ARN using Ref
Is there a way to get the name of the secret? I tried using !GetAtt LogicalIdOfSecret but that doesn’t work
The documentation only references the ARN part
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-secretsmanager-secret.html

Comment: try `!GetAtt LogicalIdOfSecret.Name`

Comment: thank you, sadly secrets dont support GetAtt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AWS::SecretsManager::Secret resource type does not support function GetAtt. You only can reference via Ref function which return the ARN.

However, using that ARN is possible to split it and get the name for most cases.
The ARN structure for Secrets is:

```
arn:aws:secretsmanager:region:account_id:secret:my_path/my_secret_name-autoid
```

So the following combination of functions (Select, Split, Ref) gives you the Secret's Name.

```
"Outputs": {
    "SecretName": {
        "Value": {
            "Fn::Select": [
                "0", {
                    "Fn::Split": [
                        "-", {
                            "Fn::Select": [
                                "6", {
                                    "Fn::Split": [
                                        ":", {
                                            "Ref": "MySecret"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }

            ]
        },
        "Description": "Secret's Name"
    }
}
```

It works fine except in the case the secret name includes dashes '-' because the split logic is based on the '-' included on the name + autogenerated value.

---

Reference:

[CloudFormation Intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html)